# Selecting a Column based on Child and Parent Category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Have a SQL server 2008 Database. I have a table with the following structure

```
CatID  ParentCatID  NAME   Level   
1        NULL        A       1
2         1          B       2
3         2          C       3  
4        NULL        D       1
5         4          E       2
6         5          F       3
7        NULL        G       1 
8         7          H       2
```

I want to Select the Name column in Heirarchical format like below:

```
Level1   Level2   Level3
  A        B        C
  D        E        F
```

In my Table all level1 categories have level2 children. Similarly all level2 children have level3 children. So how can i get the data in my desired format.

Comment: Are you just going three levels deep? Or does it need to be infinitely deep? (The latter needs Common Table Expressions.)

Comment: Thankfully its only 3 levels deep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple query like this:

```
select 
   C1.NAME as Level1, 
   C2.NAME as Level2,
   C3.NAME as Level3
from Categories C1
inner join Categories C2
   on C2.ParentCatId = C1.CatId
inner join Categories C3
   on C3.ParentCatId = C2.CatId
where C1.Level = 1 and C2.Level = 2 and C3.Level = 3 and
```